# Browser field in BlackBerry not redirecting

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an app for both BlackBerry and Android.  On Android, when I send the browser to some url, it redirects to another url with good look. But on BlackBerry for the same url it is only displaying links on the site.  It is not applying css and does not look like the Android layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blackberry browser (specially in OS versions < 6) is not as good as the Android one. There are also a couple of options in the Browser Settings that you should enable for it to load JavaScript, Background Images or PC-targeted CSS files. Sadly, there seems to be no way of automatically passing this as a parameter to the browser before opening.

You're facing a platform issue, not a developer's one. Although you could, of course, create a set of CSS files intended for Blackberry visitors, taking these limits in mind and being conscious that it will not look as good as the Android one.